# Can [std::streampos] be converted to [size_t] implicitly?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, standards, filestream

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin{ "" };
    size_t n = fin.tellg(); // ok
}
```

The code compiles ok. However, according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/fpos), I find `fin.tellg()` is a type of `std::fpos`, which doesn't define the ability to convert itself to `size_t` implicitly.

Any explanations?

Comment: `std::streampos` is an integer type that just *might* be compatible with `size_t` on your system. Just because there is no guarantee, doesn't mean that it *never* works.

Comment: You should be particularly careful with such conversion if the file happens to be very large.

Comment: It is theoretically possible that `std::fpos` is 64-bit while `size_t` is 32-bit.

Comment: @BoPersson `basic_istream::tellg()` returns `pos_type`; `pos_type` is `Traits::pos_type`; `char_traits<char>::pos_type` is `streampos`; `streampos` is `fpos<mbstate_t>`, which is not an integral type?

Comment: @BoB - Ok, I missed one step. `fpos` is implicitly convertible to `streamoff`, which is the integer type.

Comment: Your question raises another: why do you need to convert it to a `size_t` in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right about the fact that it returns an `std::fpos`. Now let's look at how it's defined:

```
template<class _Statetype>
    class fpos {<...>}
```

`fpos` also does have a conversion operator for converting into the `streamoff` type which is "stream offset" type:

```
__CLR_OR_THIS_CALL operator streamoff() const
    {   // return offset
    return ((streamoff)(_Myoff + _FPOSOFF(_Fpos)));
    }
```

On my machine `streamoff` happens to be defined as `typedef _Longlong streamoff;`, I would believe it's something similar on your machine. This is why it can be converted to `type_t`, however nothing prevents it from being larger than `type_t`, so be careful.

Answer (score 4):

"OK" on your platform. Not necessarily OK on all platforms. Whether in practice that means much depends on the circumstances. For example, on a 32-bit system, the file may be 4GB or larger, and thus not fit in the 32-bit `size_t`, where `std::fpos` is a 64-bit value and does hold the size of the file.

If the `n` is used to determine the length of the file or some such, serious problems may occur if you misjudge the total size - overwriting old data, or if you load the file and then save it based on that, you'd lose some or all of the data.

Comment: Just a minor note: The problem with loading and saving the file is more complicated - and cannot really be solved by a different type. The reason is that if the file-size doesn't fit in size_t then the file contents is unlikely to fit in memory.